# BIAB vs mash tun taste test

Tags: biab, mash-tun

I've been reading brulosophy a lot recently and I'm amazed they've not done a BIAB (brew in a bag) vs mash tun test.

It seems to me there's still a question over whether BIAB can ever fully achieve the wonders of a full mash tun system.  But i've never read anywhere where someone has compared side by side?

Also; Given the grainfather and Braumeister are effectively BIAB, it seems to me any issues are resolved these days.  (I've never heard bad things about those two systems!?)

Comment: So why don't you do it and tell us your conclusion?

Comment: Primarily as I don't have a mash tun, and hence debating whether or not it's worth getting one.  I've asked my local brew club if anyone with one wants to do the same brew and then we can do a side by side..  Of course, if we do this i'll publish the results!

Comment: I can tell you my results....I found BIAB to be a viable system for up to maybe 2-3 gal. batches.  Bigger than that and for me it becomes more effort than it's worth.  The quality of the beer was on par with what I make with any of my other systems.

Answer (score 3):

I think your over whether 'BIAB can achieve the wonders of a mash tun brewing' is only commonly understood as well as questions like 'do I need a starter'? or 'Can I possibly make beer without pure oxygen aeration?'  (The answer being: If it works for you then that is your answer)

The Mash tun, or BIAB, or partial mash (or even extract), question is not if one method or another is 'better' or worse objectively, the question to ask is Can Brewer A make beer of the same caliber as Brewer B using whatever method they see fit.
Also remember two brewers trying to make the same beer, even with the **same** equipment might make beer with noticeable differences.

Both methods have positives and negatives when you compare, but mash tuns and BIAB both make delicious beer!

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting as a comparision on efficiency and ease of brewday.

As for the final beer. You can achieve the same results in the quality of beer with both methods.

A mash tun has a lot of advantages, mainly larger batch volume, less lifting, better rinse etc.

BIAB can get amazing efficiency, mainly because you can mill grain really fine that would stick a sparge using a common false bottom.

You're correct new single kettle systems have addesses most of the BIAB limitations. Like step mashs, RIS.